# How to get file path in Asp.net core to work in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: asp.net-core, path, azure-devops

Am trying to read Text File content. So i am using below line of code it is working in local .

```
 string src = @"Templates\UserMailTemplate.txt";
 string[] content = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(src);
```

After hosting in Azure Dev Ops .Am getting issue as 
Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Templates\UserMailTemplate.txt'.

Server.Mappath is not working in ASP.Net Core .

Please let me know how can i resolve this in DEV ops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your issue is in the error message: `Could not find file`. This probably means the file is either not published, or not published at the location you're expecting it to be.

Please validate that you're looking in the right location.

To enable having the files available after publish, either
1. Have a look at [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment) and its properties
2. Set the [Build Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions) to Content and access it using `Application.GetContentStream`
3. Set the Build Action to `Embedded Resource` and call `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` to read the file from the assembly
4. Set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer` and access the files in the output directory

***'Slightly' off-topic***
Please have a look at a completely different way to manage mail templates in Azure. The easiest change from what you're doing now is probably to store them in [Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/).
If you persist in using files, please refer to this Azure Tip: [Working with Files in Azure App Service](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip20.html)